# How to test injectors on a 1999 F-350 with a 7.3

Tags: ford, diesel, fuel-injection, f-350

How do you test injectors on a 1999 F-350 with a 7.3 motor? I think it might be misfiring.

Comment: Just a safety tip in case you start pulling apart the fuel system: wait until the car is dead cold (to avoid fuel igniting on the exhaust manifold) and beware that the fuel system may be highly pressurized.

Answer (score 2):

The way I've done it is to remove the injectors and have them flow tested. Also you should remove the valve covers and run the engine to check for other fuel leaks.

Comment: Welcome to the site. If I can suggest, if you put out information like this, you should also try to include information as to *what* you are suggesting needs to be accomplished. In this case, it would mean instructions on pulling and replacing the injectors on the PowerStroke engine.